# Error on applying Matlab activations function on Siamese network

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

Happy new year

For a sample Siamese network (for instance refer to Matlab example: Train a Siamese Network to Compare Images(https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/train-a-siamese-network-to-compare-images.html)), I need to compute deep learning network layer activations (refer again to Matlab activations function (https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/seriesnetwork.activations.html)) for a specific layer. I faced an error and I have no idea to solve it. The code is as below:

**sample code to test Matlab activations function:
**

```
inp = 255*rand(105,105,1);
inp = dlarray(inp,"SSCB");
f = activations(net,inp,"maxpool_1");
```

**Matlab error:
**Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs for function 'activations'.

I tried to apply Matlab activations function on neural network object.
It work fine on pre-trained networks. But It failed on Siamese.

Comment: I am not an expert in the field, but the second argument of ```activations``` should not be a ```dlarray``` type, as discussed [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/seriesnetwork.activations.html#mw_70f86305-04b8-41c4-9276-0d1a9bcb9e96_sep_mw_99c47767-d581-463d-a32e-fd1427314607). There are functions dedicated to extracting data from a ```dlarray```, such as ```extractdata```.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.